# Dielectric tensor for a lossy medium

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

Most books and papers tell that the dielectric permittivity (and the magnetic permeability as well) tensor must have Hermitian symmetry (when phasor notation is used, not purely real time functions). But that is just in the case of lossless media.
I'm interested to the more general case of lossy ones, and that will require a rather long introduction.
First, for the time-averaged Poynting theorem
$$\nabla \cdot S=\nabla \cdot \left(\tfrac{1}{2} E \times H^* \right)=
\tfrac{1}{2} (\nabla \times E) \cdot H^*-\tfrac{1}{2} (\nabla \times H)^* \cdot E=
\frac{i \omega}{2}(-B \cdot H^*+D^* \cdot E)-\frac{J^* \cdot E}{2}$$
if we consider a medium without sources ($J=0$), take the real part and apply the property of complex numbers for which $\mathfrak{I} \{z\}=(z-z^*)/2i$
$$ \mathfrak{R}\{\nabla \cdot S\}=\frac{i \omega}{4}(E \cdot D^* - E^* \cdot D+H \cdot B^*-H^* \cdot B)$$
Because of transposition properties ($a^*M a=aM^T a^*$, where $a$ is a vector) the right hand side can be written as
$$\frac{i \omega}{4}\left[E \cdot (\varepsilon^*-\varepsilon^T) E^*+H \cdot (\mu^*-\mu^T) H^* \right]$$
Each of the two terms is a quadratic form:
$$E \cdot (\varepsilon^*-\varepsilon^T) E^* = E^T (\varepsilon^*-\varepsilon^T) E^*$$
I'm not completely sure about this, but, according to "Methods for Electromagnetic field analysis" by Ismo Lindell (p. 91), for a lossy medium, it must be a positive quantity:
$$i \omega E^T(\varepsilon^*-\varepsilon^T) E^*>0 $$
By applying complex conjugation, we get
$$-i \omega E^T(\varepsilon-\varepsilon^H) E^*<0 $$
Meaning that the matrix $-i (\varepsilon-\varepsilon^H)$ must be **negative** definite.

It reads
$$-i\begin{pmatrix}
   \varepsilon_{11}-\varepsilon_{11}^* & \varepsilon_{12}-\varepsilon_{21}^* & \varepsilon_{13}-\varepsilon_{31}^* \\
   \varepsilon_{21}-\varepsilon_{12}^* & \varepsilon_{22}-\varepsilon_{22}^* & \varepsilon_{23}-\varepsilon_{32}^* \\
   \varepsilon_{31}-\varepsilon_{13}^* & \varepsilon_{32}-\varepsilon_{32}^* & 
\varepsilon_{33}-\varepsilon_{33}^*
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 \, \varepsilon_{11_{im}} & \epsilon_{12}  & \epsilon_{13} \\
   \epsilon_{12}^*  & 2 \, \varepsilon_{22_{im}}  & \epsilon_{23} \\
   \epsilon_{13}^*  & \epsilon_{23}^*  & 2 \, \varepsilon_{33_{im}}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $\epsilon_{ij}= -i(\varepsilon_{ij}-\varepsilon_{ji}^*)=
\varepsilon_{ij_{im}}+\varepsilon_{ji_{im}}-i (\varepsilon_{ij_{r}}-\varepsilon_{ji_{r}})$.
Note that this matrix is Hermitian, therefore all of its eigenvalues are **real**.
It must be negative (or positive?) definite.
For that, there is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), stating that all principal minors must have a positive determinant, $\Delta_k >0$ (in the case of negative definiteness,  alternate signs, $(-1)^k \Delta_k>0$).
I guess that it should apply also for permutations of rows and columns, as long as the elements on the main diagonal remain there (e.g. $a_{ii}\rightarrow a_{jj}$).
If so, the first condition is that
$$\varepsilon_{ii_{im}}>0$$
This is somehow expected, as it tells that the diagonal components must have a positive imaginary component, that is, absorption/loss.
The second one is that (this in both cases, once we figure out what's the correct sign)
$$Det 
\begin{vmatrix}
   2 \, \varepsilon_{ii_{im}}  &  \epsilon_{ij} \\
   \epsilon_{ij}^*  &  2 \, \varepsilon_{jj_{im}}
\end{vmatrix}
>0
\hspace{1cm}
\text{i.e.}
\hspace{5mm}
-2 \sqrt{\varepsilon_{ii_{im}} \, \varepsilon_{jj_{im}}}<
\sqrt{(\varepsilon_{ij}+\varepsilon_{ji})_{im}^2+(\varepsilon_{ij}-\varepsilon_{ji})_{r}^2}<2 \sqrt{\varepsilon_{ii_{im}} \, \varepsilon_{jj_{im}}}
$$
and finally, that the determinant of the whole matrix is positive (or negative).
But that becomes rather complicated:
$$\Delta_3= 8 \, \varepsilon_{11_{im}} \varepsilon_{22_{im}} \varepsilon_{33_{im}}
-2 (\varepsilon_{11_{im}} |\epsilon_{23}|^2+\varepsilon_{22_{im}} |\epsilon_{13}|^2 + \varepsilon_{33_{im}} |\epsilon_{12}|^2)
+(\epsilon_{12} \epsilon_{23} \epsilon_{13}^*+\epsilon_{12}^* \epsilon_{23}^* \epsilon_{13})>0$$
I can put the previous result from $\Delta_2$ (or $|\epsilon_{ij}|^2< 4 \,  \varepsilon_{ii_{im}} \varepsilon_{jj_{im}}$), to get
$$\Delta_3>-16 \, \varepsilon_{11_{im}} \varepsilon_{22_{im}} \varepsilon_{33_{im}} + 2 \mathfrak{R} \{ \epsilon_{12} \epsilon_{23} \epsilon_{13}^* \}$$
I don't know if there is a way to get clearer inequalities, I mean something regarding $\varepsilon_{ij}$ alone with respect to the other ones.